Intermediate rules not being executed, using checkpoints
I'm using Snakemake 7.32.4.
The issue:
Rules upstream of my last rule are not being recognized as dependencies, and are thus not being called, which leads to errors.

EDIT:
Made a few changes to the script, and it seems to work now! The amended script for completeness:
import os

configfile: "config/config.yaml"

rule all:
    input:
        "results/{gene_symbol}/phyloP_scores_null_annotated.RDS".format(gene_symbol=config["gene_symbol"])
        # "results/{gene_symbol}/phyloP_scores_distro.pdf".format(gene_symbol=config["gene_symbol"])
    
rule get_gene_lengths:
    output:
       temp("gene_lengths.bed")
    conda:
        "envs/bed_env.yaml"
    shell:
        """
        gff2bed --do-not-sort < resources/{config[gtf_file]} | 
            awk '$8 ~ "gene" {{print $0, $3 - $2}}' > {output}
        """

checkpoint subset_gtf_by_length:
    input:
        "gene_lengths.bed"
    output:
        directory("null_beds/{gene_symbol}")
    params:
        ensembl_id=config["ensembl_id"],
        length_error=config["length_error"]
    script:
        "scripts/subset_gtf_by_length.sh"

rule melt_bed_null:
    input:
        "null_beds/{gene_symbol}/gene{i}.bed"
    output:
        "null_beds_melted/{gene_symbol}/melted_gene{i}.bed"
    script:
        "scripts/melt_bed.sh"

rule intersect_scores_null:
    input:
        "null_beds_melted/{gene_symbol}/melted_gene{i}.bed"
    output:
        "null_scores/{gene_symbol}/phyloP_scores{i}.tsv"
    params:
        phylo_file="resources/" + config["phylo_file"]
    conda:
        "envs/bed_env.yaml"
    script:
        "scripts/intersect_scores.sh"
           
def fetch_null_scores(wildcards):
    checkpoint_dir = checkpoints.subset_gtf_by_length.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    null_scores = expand("null_scores/{gene_symbol}/phyloP_scores{i}.tsv", 
                         gene_symbol=wildcards.gene_symbol,
                         i=glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "gene{i}.bed")).i)
    # print(checkpoint_dir)
    # print(null_scores)
    return null_scores

rule annotate_null:
    input:
        fetch_null_scores
    output:
        temp("results/{gene_symbol}/phyloP_scores_null_annotated.RDS")
    params:
        annotatr_file="resources/" + config["annotatr_file"],
        n_threads=config["n_threads"]
    conda:
        "envs/r_phylop_workflow.yaml"
    script:
        "scripts/annotate_null.R"


I also do not know ahead of time how many outputs there will being starting with the rule "subset_gtf_by_length".
I'm modeling this code off of the Snakemake documentation for using checkpoints with variable numbers of outputs:
https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html
Here is my Snakefile:
import os
import glob
import yaml

configfile: "config/config.yaml"

with open("config/config.yaml", "r") as config_file:
    config = yaml.safe_load(config_file)

gene_symbol = config["gene_symbol"]

rule all:
    input:
        "results/{gene_symbol}_phyloP_scores_null_annotated.RDS".format(gene_symbol=gene_symbol)
        # "results/{gene_symbol}_phyloP_scores_distro.pdf".format(gene_symbol=gene_symbol)
    
rule get_gene_lengths:
    output:
       temp("gene_lengths.bed")
    params:
        gtf=config["gtf_file"]
    conda:
        "envs/bedops.yaml"
    shell:
        """
        gff2bed --do-not-sort < resources/{params.gtf} | 
            awk '$8 ~ "gene" {{print $0, $3 - $2}}' > {output}
        """
        
checkpoint subset_gtf_by_length:
    input:
        "gene_lengths.bed"
    output:
        directory("null/{gene_symbol}") 
    params:
        ensembl_id=config["ensembl_id"],
        length_error=config["length_error"]
    script:
        "scripts/subset_gtf_by_length.sh"

rule melt_bed_null:
    input:
        "null/{gene_symbol}/gene{i}.bed"
    output:
        "null/{gene_symbol}/melted_gene{i}.bed"
    script:
        "scripts/melt_bed.sh"

rule intersect_scores_null:
    input:
        "null/{gene_symbol}/melted_gene{i}.bed"
    output:
        "null/{gene_symbol}/phyloP_scores{i}.tsv"
    params:
        phylo_file="resources/" + config["phylo_file"]
    conda:
        "envs/bedtools.yaml"
    script:
        "scripts/intersect_scores.sh"
        
def fetch_null_scores(wildcards):
    checkpoint_dir = checkpoints.subset_gtf_by_length.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    return expand("null/{gene_symbol}/phyloP_scores{i}.txt", 
                  gene_symbol=wildcards.gene_symbol,
                  i=glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "phyloP_scores{i}.txt")).i)

rule annotate_null:
    input:
        fetch_null_scores
    output:
        "results/{gene_symbol}_phyloP_scores_null_annotated.RDS" # .format(gene_symbol=gene_symbol)
    params:
        n_threads=config["n_threads"],
        annotatr_file="resources/" + config["annotatr_file"]
    conda:
        "envs/r_env.yaml"
    shell:
        """echo {input}
        """

When I run snakemake -n, the rules "melt_bed_null" and "intersect_scores_null" aren't being called:
Job stats:
job                     count
--------------------  -------
all                         1
annotate_null               1
get_gene_lengths            1
subset_gtf_by_length        1
total                       4

... suggesting that they aren't being detected as dependencies for "annotate_null".
When I actually run the script, it jumps from the rule "subset_gtf_by_length" to "annotate_null", which naturally leads to errors.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I never used checkpoints before so I am probably no help, but still I don't get two things: A) why is your fetch function not part of the melt_bed_null-rule, isn't this the part which first works with the output of your checkpoint rule . And B) do you have multiple phyloP_scores{i} for every gene_symbol if so i think you need to have the input of annotate_null as a list in order to combine all the is into your rds.

Hi @kEks; the script use in the melt_bed_null rule is something I use elsewhere, so ideally I don't want to include a line that creates the output directory in subset_gtf_by_length. Worst case, I can create separate scripts and try using the checkpoint later. However, the example provided in the documentation has an intermediate rule between the checkpoint and the rule that uses the checkpoint directory, so I'm not sure why my setup should be different. To your second point, I do have multiple phyloP_scores{i} per gene_symbol. I'll try changing the output to a list as you suggest. Thanks!

It's difficult to diagnose without an example I can reproduce locally, but I would suggest checking that the expand in fetch_null_scores is working as you expect. You can check this with a print statement.
It's possible that it is just returning an empty list (maybe because the glob wildcards didn't match the pattern), if this is the case then annotate_null will have no input, leading to the intermediate rules not needing to be run.

speaking of matching patterns: the output of intersect_scores_null is a .tsv, while the expand function expects a .txt

@kEks You're right, I fixed this. Still facing the same issue.

@kEks Fixed a few more bugs, and it works now. Thank you!
